# While loop only runs on first line of file

Tags: bash, shell-script

For some reason my `while` loop is only running one time. I've looked through other posts but I can't seem to figure it out. Should be a simple script but it will only run once. Screen output is below with `+x` in the bash script.

```
LICENSE="1010110.license"
PASS="somepassword"
SSHPASS="/usr/bin/sshpass"
SERVERFILE="/home/user/server.txt"

while read SERVER
do
    if sshpass -p $PASS ssh root@$SERVER '[ -d /etc/something/licenses/ ]'
         then
            echo "The directory is present"
            sshpass -p "$PASS" scp $LICENSE "root@$SERVER":/etc/something/licenses/
         else
            echo "$SERVER does not contain the correct folder, trying 2nd option" >> failures.txt
            if sshpass -p $PASS ssh root@$SERVER '[ -d /etc/something/else/licenses/ ]' 
                then
                    sshpass -p "$PASS" scp $LICENSE "root@$SERVER":/etc/something/else/licenses/
                else
                    echo "$SERVER does not contain either directory" >> failures.txt
            fi

    fi

done < "$SERVERFILE"
```

Here is the output with `+x`

```
+ read SERVER
+ sshpass -p 'somepassword' ssh root@server1 '[ -d /etc/something/licenses/ ]'
+ echo 'server1 does not contain the correct folder, trying 2nd option'
+ sshpass -p 'somepassword' ssh root@server1 '[ -d /etc/something/else/licenses/ ]'
+ sshpass -p 'somepassword' scp 1010110.license root@server1:/etc/something/else/licenses/
+ read SERVER
```

It looks like it tries to read `SERVER` again but doesn't actually go through it. The `server.txt` file is just a list of server names.

Comment: In all likelihood some of the commands inside the loop ate stdin

Comment: See [BashFAQ #89: I'm reading a file line by line and running ssh or ffmpeg, only the first line gets processed!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) My favorite fix is to use `while read SERVER <&3` and `done 3< "$SERVERFILE"` (the second fix listed in the FAQ).

Comment: You have this one as well: https://superuser.com/questions/1236851/what-is-wrong-with-this-while-loop also suggesting the same in its last fix option (of the chosen reply).

Comment: Thanks fellas -- these solutions look good. Very cool. Adding `<&3` and `done 3< "$SERVERFILE"` worked for me.